# How to resolve a 'The report "report.custom" already exists!' error while launching OpenERP 7.0

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Running Ubuntu 12.04, I try to run OpenERP 7.0, using the latest tarball archive.

```
wget "http://nightly.openerp.com/7.0/nightly/src/openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz"
tar -xzf openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz
# cd extracted directory
./openerp-server  —xmlrpc-port=40069 —netrpc-port=40070 —addons-path=openerp/addons,openerp/web/addons
```

Here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./openerp-server", line 5, in <module>
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 51, in main
    __import__(m)
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/addons/account_test/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import report
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/addons/account_test/report/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import account_test_report
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/addons/account_test/report/account_test_report.py", line 25, in <module> 
    from report import report_sxw
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/report/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    import custom
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/report/custom.py", line 623, in <module>
    report_custom('report.custom')
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/report/custom.py", line 58, in __init__
    report_int.__init__(self, name)
  File "/path/to/decrompressed/directory/openerp-7.0-20140113-001013/openerp/report/interface.py", line 45, in __init__
    assert not self.exists(name), 'The report "%s" already exists!' % name
AssertionError: The report "report.custom" already exists!
```

I already successfully runned a 6.0 instance on this same machine, this server is not running while I try to launch the 7.0 version though. I don't know if that may be related to the fact I already installed the 6.0 before. Could it be a PostgreSQL problem? I didn't drop the existing 6.0 database.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Running the server without more parameters seems to work:

```
./openerp-server
2014-01-13 14:26:35,270 1014 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140113-001013
…
```

Comment: You are just avoiding usage of addons, where bug hidden. It's not fix.